# unity Bézier Path creator android moving problem is start laggy when scene changed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, path, bezier

> Im using bêziers path not vertex one. And in editor(windows) there is
> no problem with it. im building for android and trying to play with
> galaxy m21. first scene is completely normal. but when it comes for
> other scenes it start moving laggy (because of path follower i think).
> (im not talking about side walks just movement to forward along the
> path)
>
> there is 4 scene and this is looping when click next level in the end.
> if we return to first scene that one starts to laggy movement.
>
> game is a little city we move in streets so i was thinking maybe
> render based problem so i delete every gameobject about city it became
> almost some kind of empty space and tried, same problem.
>
> also i was using different gameobject to follow pathfollower so i
> remove that and put my player directly inside pathfollower but it
> remains same. when i go next level it starts moving laggy not smooth.
> (i understand it because there is trail and shaking time to time)
>
> finaly i add game manager's awake() System.GC.Collect();
> Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets(); maybe it helps when nextlevel loaded.
> but still it is laggy forward movement.
>
> any idea what is going on? i can take any suggestion thanks for help.

Comment: Are you loading scenes asynchronously?

Comment: oh thanks for reply. i tried both way but thats not the case

Answer (score 0):

i just find it i was using Dotween for side movement but it was using x,y and *z* That was my problem.

I dont know how it works when its first loaded. I mean if i load the game and play it works first level but other levels  starting >
-sorry i dont know exactly word but its lagging/freezing in the movement.-

But if i close app and start again, that same level works just fine.

Anyway i just tried to disable that script at tried and i see no shaking/freezing in the trail so, i think that was the problem, thats my fault i think like i said, i'm new :)

now i try use tween except the *z* or try completely diffrent thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i made it to run smoothly.

Go to PathFollower and turn off EnableTransforms
[click to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2wRN.png)

This will don't ruin everything.